# Inline editing of page metadata

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, metadata

We want our users to be able to link a component to the page metadata from `XPM`. Switching components is less user friendly in this case, so we are wondering whether it's possible to inline edit Page Metadata from the experience manager?

We are using `Tridion 2013 SP1`.

**Clarification**: We would like to be able to inline edit page metadata just like we are able to edit component fields and component metadata fields inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline editing of (pure) Page Metadata is not a feature that is available in XPM at this time,  so you have two options:

1. Use the Metadata in the properties and edit it there (not inline)
2. Make the Metadata of the Page a Component link, and store all its Metadata in a Component

When using option #2, you can write out the Metadata on the Page using `@@RenderComponentPresentation(compId, templateId)@@` (you will need a Component Template too). Since a Component Presentation is inline editable, you will now have your Page Metadata also inline editable.

If most (or all) of the Page Metadata is not directly visible on the Page (i.e. it is used for things like keywords and description in the HTML page head) I would opt for option #1. Otherwise it could be worth exploring option #2.

Comment: Thanks for the response and workaround. We'll look into what we'll do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible for sure.
You select the Border of the page and in the right side you will see a blue icon which will show you the properties windows, alternatively you can click the properties button on the Ribbon of Experience manager. In the properties windows, you will see Edit Metadata button.

You can edit your metadata from here.

Further you can refer the User Manual for XPM which is available [HERE](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/SDL%20Tridion%202013%20Experience%20Manager%20Basic%20User%20Manual_tcm89-20974.pdf) and navigate to the page number 29 on it to get a step by step process

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Thanks for your answer. After reading it, I realised my question was formulated poorly. I clarified it a bit. We want to be able to `inline` edit page metadata. Just like component (metadata) fields. You got an upvote because it is of course the right answer on my original question.